# invalid_grant, bad request when refreshing a webpage after signed in though google api

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

i have successfully integrated google api login and logout and both are working fine but after i logged in and try to refresh the webpage .. it shows me the below error-

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST  https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error":
> "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" } in
> C:\xamppNew\htdocs\realestate\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113 Stack
> trace: #0 C:\xamppNew\htdocs\realestate\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(69):
> GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request),
> Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL, Array, NULL) #1
> C:\xamppNew\htdocs\realestate\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(204):
> GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #2
> C:\xamppNew\htdocs\realestate\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(153):
> GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL) #3
> C:\xamppNew\htdocs\realestate\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(48):
> GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}() #4 C:\xamppNew\ht in
> C:\xamppNew\htdocs\realestate\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113

My config.php -

```
<?php


session_start();


require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';


$google_client = new Google_Client();

$google_client->setAccessType('offline');

$google_client->setClientId('client key');


 $google_client->setClientSecret('client secret key');


$google_client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/realestate/index.php');


$google_client->addScope('email');

$google_client->addScope('profile');

?>
```

My index.php google api session codes-

```
<?php


include('config.php');

$login_button = '';


if(isset($_GET["code"]))
{

$token = $google_client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET["code"]);


if(!isset($token['error']))
{

$google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);


$_SESSION['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];


$google_service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($google_client);


$data = $google_service->userinfo->get();


    if(!empty($data['given_name']))
    {
    $_SESSION['user_first_name'] = $data['given_name'];
    }

    if(!empty($data['family_name']))
    {
    $_SESSION['user_last_name'] = $data['family_name'];
    }

    if(!empty($data['email']))
    {
    $_SESSION['user_email_address'] = $data['email'];
    }

    if(!empty($data['gender']))
    {
    $_SESSION['user_gender'] = $data['gender'];
    }

    if(!empty($data['picture']))
    {
        $_SESSION['user_image'] = $data['picture'];
    }
    }
 }


if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{

$login_button = '<a href="'.$google_client->createAuthUrl().'">Login With 
Google</a>';
}

?>


//this is for testing purpose 
<?php  if($login_button == '') {echo '<h3><b>Name :</b> 
'.$_SESSION['user_first_name'].' '.$_SESSION['user_last_name'].'</h3>';
                            echo '<h3><a href="logout.php">Logout</h3> 
</div>'; }?>
```

//this is the login button-

```
<?php echo '<a class="btn connect-google">'.$login_button . '</a>'; ?>
```

My logout.php-

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$accesstoken=$_SESSION['access_token'];
//Reset OAuth access token
$google_client->revokeToken($accesstoken);

//Destroy entire session data.
session_destroy();

//redirect page to index.php
header('location:index');

?>
```

I have no idea how why it is happening and how to fix this. Btw after i logged in though google api  in my website and refresh the page , it should refresh successfully while staying logged in . But it shows me the error and when i click back it takes to me google login  page again.

Comment: The `code` value you get back from the login dialog, can only be exchanged for a token _once_ - and you are trying to make that same request a second time here. Simplest solution would probably, that you redirect to the current URL _minus_ that `code` parameter, after you performed this step.

Comment: @DaImTo no, I have not worked with this particular library, bit I know a bit about how OAuth works. And I don’t know what you consider “handling all those calls itself”, when https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-oauth shows several specific steps that need to be performed. If step #6 there gets performed _twice_ (because a page with `code=…` somewhere in the query string gets _reloaded_), then it would be only natural to get an error in that exact situation.

Comment: You don’t need to give _me_ that much grief, for _them_ not showing any code. On that part, we are in total agreement.

Comment: @DaImTo i have updated all codes login and logout and config in the question plz check the edits.

Comment: @CBroe i have updated all codes login and logout and config in the question plz check the edits.

Comment: from your comments i realized that i should have put a refresh token but i dont know where to get the refresh token in console.cloud.google.com or is it just a method. Please give me an idea or a sample if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that your not using your refresh token properly

## [oauth2callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20People%20API/v1/oauth2callback.php)

Notice how when the code is returned that i am storing both the access token and the refresh token into the session.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = buildClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client = buildClient();
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
    // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
    //Redirect back to main script
    $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

## [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20People%20API/v1/Oauth2Authentication.php)

Then check this to see how i test if the access token is expired and if it is i use the refresh token to fetch a new one.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    $client = getOauth2Client();

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed.
 * Example:  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function buildClient(){
    
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());  
    return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the redirect uri.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app#choosingredirecturi
 * Hostname and current server path are needed to redirect to oauth2callback.php
 * @return A redirect uri.
 */
function getRedirectUri(){

    //Building Redirect URI
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                    //returns the current URL
    if(strrpos($url, '?') > 0)
        $url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '?') );  // Removing any parameters.
    $folder = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') );   // Removeing current file.
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $folder. '/oauth2callback.php';
}


/**
 * Authenticating to Google using Oauth2
 * Documentation:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Returns a Google client with refresh token and access tokens set. 
 *  If not authencated then we will redirect to request authencation.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {
        
        $client = buildClient();
        
        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }
        
        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            
            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 
            
            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

## userinfo

Also you should consider going though the People api instead of the userinfo endpoint its much more stable when requesting user profile information, as you are already requesting email and profile scopes you should already have access.

Comment: ok i believe i understand some of what you stated above. But can you tell me one thing ?    the full url after logged in is ---------------------------------------------------------------index.php?code=4%2F0AY0e-g4SymqnegtibqVf1xeta3OL3kLZqpk_Y4o3Htp4nUFhlZPxUKK6wkVpK1F3o3UXLw&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid&authuser=1&prompt=consent#       ------------------------------- and if i remove the part after '?' and refresh the page , now it refreshs succesfully. why it happens ?

Comment: You have index.php set up as the redirect uri set to in Google developer console. The redirect uri is the page that's prepared to handle the call back from the authorization server.  In my case its set to oauth2callback.php which is the file that's prepared to handle the call back from the authorization server.  Then it forwards the user back to index.php which includes all the functions from Oauth2Authentication.php

Comment: how do i call the login button in index page if i use the approach you gave above?

Comment: You should be able to call $client->createAuthUrl(); like you normally do.  I am going to add this to my list of videos / tutorials.   Its a nice use case with your button.

Comment: i tried this approach but when i point redirect uri to oauth2callback.php , it directly opens it causing to open google signin page in a loop again and again :( So is there any way to add refresh access token using the code i gave in question?

Comment: did you change the oauth2callback.php and set "oauth2callback.php" to be your index.php page since you don't have Oauth2Authentication.php or did you copy that file as well.

Comment: I created both files as you said. And put the oauth2callback.php as redirect uri